# I am having problem with making my character Dash using Shift keys

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, debugging, ienumerator

```
Movement Move;
public float DashSpeed;
private float DashTime;

// Start is called before the first frame update
void Start()
{
    Move=GetComponent<Movement>();
}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update()
{
    if(Input.GetKey(KeyCode.LeftShift)||Input.GetKey(KeyCode.RightShift))
    {
      StartCoroutine(Dashing()); 
    
    }
}
    I am unable to understand what happened despite following the tutorial correctly.Hey I changed the method name but I am ecountering a new bug
```

`IEnumerator Dashing() { float startTime= Time.time;`

```
        while(Time.time < startTime + DashTime)
        {
            Move.Movement.Move(Move.runSpeed * DashSpeed *Time.deltaTime);
          
            yield return null;`
         }                        
        }
    }
}
```

I did understood that I don't have a character controller as component like the guy on the tutorial but I have to remove the bug before putting it how can I do it.

Comment: Did you set DashTime correctly? From this code, DashTime hasn't been set so startTime + DashTime will always be startTime, hence it doesn't actually enter that while loop.

Comment: Actually I am having Cs0542 this error is in IEnumerator Dash

Answer (score 1):

As you mentioned in the comments, you have **Error CS0542** and the error occurs because the name of your **method** is the same as the name of the **class**.

> Error CS0542: member names cannot be the same as their enclosing type

```cs
public class Dash
{
    IEnumerator Dash ()
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

Just change the method name to something else.